# How to create a common function accepting different parameter type

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, servicenow

Consider the below code:

```
var list = new SomeServiceType
{
    Url = "htp://www.test.com/",
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
};
```

This code has been repeated many say as 10 times. So, I decided to use a common function that accepting this above code when passing different type.

I need to get the *Url* and *Credentials* as the response from newly created function.

For reference, SomeServiceType is ServiceNowType, 
UserName and Password are type String.

I tried with

```
public List<object>(....strucked here...)
{
  ...
  return ...//again strucked here....(neeed to return url and credentials)..
}
```

url is of type string and NetworkCredential is of c# class

Comment: How to return the response as I mentioned in the question ?

Comment: You want to return the list variable isn't it?

Comment: Yes, need to return as a list.

Comment: And return type may be SomeServiceType or ServiceNowType both?

Comment: Return type `SomeServiceType` has the fields `Url` and `Credentials`. We will pass this list for further process.

Comment: If you need only one return type then the answer have been posted by @Bharat and #Sinatr . And if you need more than one (dynamic) return type from the same function then I am answering.

Comment: Yes, I need dynamic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113305/discussion-between-868k-and-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection and activator to create method, as below

```
 public T MyMethod<T>(string url, string userName, string userPassword) {
       var myService = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo URL = myService.GetType().GetProperty("Url");
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo NetworkCred = myService.GetType().GetProperty("Credentials");
      URL.SetValue(myService, url, null);
      NetworkCred.SetValue(myService, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword), null);
      return (T)myService;
   }
```

Call As

```
var list =  MyMethod<SomeServiceType>(url,userName,userPassword);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks, Great Solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like these in asp.net.

```
        public static List<SomeServiceType> MyFunction(string url, string UserName, string Password)
        {
            List<SomeServiceType> list = new List<SomeServiceType>();
            if (url != null && UserName != null && Password != null)
            {
                list = new SomeServiceType()
                {
                    Url = "htp://www.test.com/",
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
                };
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: This Can't give the solution.

Comment: hi @StackOverflow, i just give you an example of how to get your desired output, as i don't have your proper data, i can't give you exact code.